2 CAT6 cables in the same conduit. Which one is which?
I have a conduit that goes to four different buildings - from one building to the next. The conduit has two CAT6 cables. I need to splice the cable in each of the buildings, while leaving one cable uncut from beginning to end.
My Fluke tone generator (Pro 3000) cannot help me identify which cable is which.
Any ideas on how I can determine which cable to cut?

"I need to splice the cable in each of the buildings" Splices are not allowed. You will not get it to pass the category test suite.

See this answer, including the part about, "Also, splices, taps, couplers, etc., are not allowed in a cable run."

Identifying a cable seems to be more appropriate for [electronics.se].

A tone generator should do the trick. The only other way I can think of is reading the markings on the cables; odds are they have different distance marks on them. (i.e. one starts at 200 and the other 500...)
